# How do I define the block visibility for content types and term pages?

Tags: 8, blocks

I have a block and I want to show it for specific content types and taxonomy terms. There is no common pattern for those pages.

For example, the URLs could be the following ones:

- http://example.com/rolling-stones (a taxonomy term page)
- http://example.com/drupal/rolling-stones (a *Basic* node)
- http://example.com/rolling-stones-part-1 (an *Article* node)
- http://example.com/demo-content (a *Demo* node)

I don't want to show the block on the *Demo* content type, but on nodes of the content types, and term pages, without cloning/replicating the block.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You'll need to use the conditions available when you edit the block. If conditions you need are missing, it's easy to create your own using the Condition API

Comment: Code won't help much when there is no common pattern. To build complex conditions try https://www.drupal.org/project/block_visibility_groups and the linked modules on the project page.

Comment: @4k4 Thank You, this module helped me and I got the results as desired.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I control block visibility with code?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203308/how-can-i-control-block-visibility-with-code)

Answer (score 0):

If you control the code for the block, then it really is a simple matter of:

- Defining the correct cache contexts (path probably)
- In the build method, determining the context (getting current node, tax info from the node, and the like.)
- Deciding what to output for the context
- If you don't want to display it, return and empty build array (or NULL).

If you don't control the block content (e.g. view or 3rd party module), you can do the same as above and use the various methods to render the block from code.