# Programmatically creating a custom block

Tags: views, blocks

I followed the steps from https://www.webwash.net/programmatically-create-block-drupal-8/.
I have a view already created and I want to render this view in this block. 
I can't find a good documentation for *build()* function.

The reason is that I want to hide the view for a role implicitly included by authenticated role.

How can I display the existing view inside the custom block I've created?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I control block visibility with code?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203308/how-can-i-control-block-visibility-with-code)

Comment: No, I said already that I want to display an existing view.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I didn't find a way to display the view and restrict for certain roles.

But I've managed to solve the problem in another way.

I created a script in *Admin > Structure > Block > My_Block > Configure > Visibility PHP*:

```
<?php 
$match = TRUE;
$heh = \Drupal::currentUser()->getAccount()->getRoles(TRUE);
$hide_from_roles = array('administrator', 'sefii', 'membership');
 if (count(array_intersect($heh, $hide_from_roles)) > 0) {
    $match = FALSE;
}
return $match;
?>
```