# How do I set a condition to only show a block to a group members?

Tags: 8, group

Is there a way to check whether a user is a group member when the user visits the group page? I have some blocks that should be hidden if an user is not a member.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I control block visibility with code?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203308/how-can-i-control-block-visibility-with-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programmatically you can use `Group::getMember()` to determine if an account is a member of a group.

```
if ($group->getMember(\Drupal::currentUser())) {
  // the current user is a member of the group.
}
```

Note that `Group::getMember()` returns a `GroupMembership` entity.

You could then create a condition plugin, using the above methodology to determine if the current user is a member of the group. I've created a tutorial on how to use the Conditions API to create conditions plugins, using this example of a condition where a member is a member of the group: https://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/custom-block-visibility-plugins-and-condition-plugin-api

Comment: Thanks! Where should I put this code? And is het possible to make a twig variabele, so I can do a if statement in a twig file?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't read your post clearly to see you were looking for block visibility based on membership. My code won't help with that.

Comment: Oh, do you have any other suggestions for me?

Comment: Nothing module based unfortunately, hopefully someone else will pop in. I've updated my post with a little more information, but implementing it requires an understanding of Drupal development, and how to create Drupal modules. The link provided explains how to create a condition plugin. These plugins are the options you have on block settings pages to determine whether a block should be shown or not.

Comment: Thanks! It's weird, right? This should be a default function in the Group module, that is the reason why people use groups. Because of the permissions. What if I develop a small module to check if an user is a member or not on the current group page. Which hook do I need?

Comment: I created a tutorial that explains how to do what you want, though you'll need to first learn how to create Drupal modules to follow it. I've linked to it in my response above.