# Conditionally display headers on web page in page.html.twig

Tags: theming

We have a header which contains a secondary menu on top bar, search, main menu and logo in page.html.twig.

We would like to implement a new header with quite a few changes and so would like to add a bool field or some field, somewhere for example all Content Types. So the user, adds a page sees this field and if checked to display new header. Is this possible?

Comment: The answer is: yes. I would probably do this with a custom block and then use blockAccess or hook_block_access to hide it given the current node's checkbox value. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203308/how-can-i-control-block-visibility-with-code

Comment: But you could also do this in hook_preprocess_page where you check if the current route is node canonical, get the node, get the value and set a custom variable you then can if-else in the page template.

Comment: Thank you, I am complete newbie to Drupal. I cannot change the current header to block, it is directly implemented in page.twig.html. It is new header I can work with.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually access nodes directly from page.html.twig.

It's not as clean as a preprocess approach, but you could do something like this:

```
{% if node is not empty %}
  {% if node.field_some_field is not empty and node.field_some_field.value == true %}
    {# Output new header #}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```